# Missing compiler in Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt, compiler-construction, compiler-errors, qt-creator

I recently installed **Qt creator 2.8.1** online on my **win Vista 32 bit** machine.

To start with Qt I wrote simple pushbutton code. And when I tried to build it shows error message saying

> Qt Creator needs compiler set up to build. Configure a compiler in kit
>   option

I tried with that Kit option din't work. what do I do?

PS Thank You

Comment: windows doesn't come with a compiler installed, you'll need to install one

Comment: i.e download visual studio express. Available for free. mingw is another option.

Comment: I tried downloading Mingw and then tried to set path of downloaded compiler in QT kit option, still the same error it shows. I am kind of newbie so I am not getting all this any idea. @ratchetfreak

Comment: As i see within the Qt directory there is gcc.exe within bin sub directory is this the compiler? @REDSOFTADAIR

Comment: I am not deep into that stuff. Did you try (after opening your Qt Project in QtCreator): Projects Tab (in the left Toolbar), then ToolChain -> Edit.

Comment: Qt dectecting compiler now.. opted option 1, i.e downloaded visual studio express 2010 .. Qt automatically detected compiler
but now debugger is missing, any idea..what now?

PS Thanks @REDSOFTADAIR

Comment: I usually dont use QTs debuger, and i cant tell how to configure it. Use Visual Studio for debugging. Simple to do and much better for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Simply refer to MINGW online install available at Qt's official downloads( http://download.qt-project.org/). You need not do anything. It will automatically detect an kits and will compile successfully.